# How to extract co-efficient of A,b,f from .lp format in C++

Tags: c++, linear-programming

I am trying with benchmark problem of lp problem . I have found several websites about this benchmark . In one site , I have found the format of lp problem as follows :

min c'x subject to Ax = b, l <= x <= u

File Format:

```
nrow  (number of rows in A)
ncol  (number of cols in A)
Anz   (number of nonzeros in A)
dcost (add to cost to get original cost)

Ap    (column pointers, ncol+1 integer)
Ai    (row indices of nonzeros in A, Anz integer)
Ax    (numerical values of nonzeros in A ,Anz real)
b     (nrow real)
c     (ncol real)
l     (ncol real)
u     (ncol real)

Ap (j) = location of start of column j
Ai (Ap (j)) through Ai (Ap (j+1)-1) are the row indices in column j
Ax (Ap (j)) through Ax (Ap (j+1)-1) are the numerical values in column j
```

I cant understand how can I form 2D array `A[][]` from Ap,Ai and Ax . Suppose for example what will be the format of this problem according to above format :

```
Minimize w = 2x1 + 10x2 + 8x3
subject to   2x1 + 2x2 + 2x3 >= 6
             2x2 + 2x3 >= 8
             -2x1 + 2x2 + 2x3 >= 4
bound to x1>=0,x2>=0,x3>=0
```

A[][] for the above problem is as follows :

```
2 2 2 
0 2 2 
-2 2 2
```

I have to extract the co-efficient of A and b in C++ . Plz help me .

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a place to have other people write code for you.  You can either make an attempt and post your code if you have a problem with it, or there are places where you can go to pay people to write code for you.   Here's the kind of questions appropriate for stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I cant understand how to extract A[ ][ ] from Ap,AiAnd Ax . I can write code myself

Comment: If you don't have a problem writing code and you don't have a problem with your code, why is this tagged with `c++`?  Perhaps it would be better to ask at https://math.stackexchange.com/ if the question is purely mathematical?

Comment: please provide a file link where data written in .lp format

Comment: In which language did you try ? C or C++ ? please provide some code you have tried so far

Comment: Am I right in thinking that what you want to do is to populate a 2d array from some file format? Because if so, you should edit your question to remove all the bits of it that aren't relevant to file formats or arrays, and you should provide an actual example of the file format you're trying to read.

Comment: You have to convert from a columnwise​ organization to a rowwise reprentstion.

Comment: How can I do that ? A simple example is enough for me . Can you help me ?

Comment: If you can't do that yourself, what are you hoping to be able to do with the matrix after all?